Forwarding JSDoc for object members whose source is a variable
I have a function documented with JSDoc which then becomes part of an object literal.
How can I forward the documentation for the function to the object literal, and thus make it available to an external scope (such as outside an outer function, or a different module)?
I could write the JSDoc on the object literal itself, but I don't want to move the JSDoc from the function.
const { printRandom } = (() => {
    /**
     * Prints a random number
     */
    const printRandom = () => console.log(Math.random())

    return {
        printRandom
    }
})()

In other words, in VSCode when hovering over the printRandom variable in the outer scope, I would like to see the text Prints a random number instead of just the function signature.

Some additional notes

While VS Code doesn't display the JS Doc at the variable exported from the function/module, it does display at the function call site:

But it doesn't do so at the usage site of arbitrary variables/properties, so the question is still useful.



"I don't want to move the JSDoc from the function": I'm empathetic to this, but that's simply not how JSDoc works. Here's an example demonstrating how to accomplish your goal — annotate the immediately-invoked function's return type using the TypeScript type including the JSDoc description. Does that fully address your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer.

@jsejcksn My actual code is far more complex than the simple example provided here. I'm afraid it's rather important to me to have the JSDoc alongside the function body, and not with some separate type annotation.

@jsejcksn See my answer.

Instead of keeping the documentation separate from the object literal, it is possible to move the documentation to within the object literal.
const { printRandom, foo } = (() => {
    return {
        /**
         * Prints a random number
         */
        printRandom: () => console.log(Math.random()),

        /**
         * Arbitrary number
         */
        foo: 4
    }
})()

This works at the object destructuring (into printRandom and foo) and also at the usage sites of both functions and variables (at least, for VS Code).


In the question you list a requirement: "I don't want to move the JSDoc from the function": but this places the documentation on the object property, not the function.

@jsejcksn If the only function definition is within the object literal, that works for me. OFC I can't do this if say printRandom was being used in other members of the object literal.

There is an alternative, you can document the function separately and then assign it to the object property:
/**
 * Prints a random number
 * @function
 */
const printRandom = () => console.log(Math.random());

const obj = {
    printRandom
};

const { printRandom: exportedPrintRandom } = obj;


This doesn't answer the question, which states that I want to make it available to an external scope (such as outside an outer function, or a different module). In my case, I need it in a different module, but the basic problem of an external scope is the same AFAICT.
